# How to get Logging using oidc-client with Angular

Tags: oidc-client-js

I am using oidc-client with angular 7, and I want to enable logging. The doc suggests that I can do the following

```
Oidc.Log.logger = console;
```

I have not been able to make this work as Oidc does not appear to be on the window object??

Comment: Did you find the answer? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 13):

Just add this to your code for javascript

```
Log.logger = console;
Log.level = Log.DEBUG;
```

and the correct import

```
import { Log } from 'oidc-client';
```

For typescript, add the following

```
import { Log } from 'oidc-client-ts';
Log.setLogger(console);
Log.setLevel(Log.DEBUG);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated with typescript syntax